# Should I be worried about brown spots on my mint leaves?

Tags: leaves, diseases

Found some brown spots on the old mint leaves on my new planted cuttings. Is this normal or a sign of disease? They're planted indoors at around 70°[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to stick my neck out here and say no- pick off affected leaves if your worried and keep the soil clean, pop outside as soon as possible and plant in a large pot with ordinary garden soil- nothing special/fancy. If you plant directly into the soil, you will regret it for the entire lifetime of the garden whilst your there- it suckers every where and comes up where you don't want it to! so never plant it directly into your garden! big pots only! take cuttings next time from the roots and do it every few years or so to keep it healthy- old plants don't make good plants when it comes to mint. The plants in the photos look very good and could even be split apart into separate pots- being outside will harden them off and increase ventilation thus avoiding any fungus's, keep the soil clean by removing any dead leaves and remove any other weeds that might spring up- other than that, they are completely hardy and regrow again next year with fresh new growth(die down during the winter)and live for years and years! hope it helps